# NSLog: log file rotation / file limits / size limits

Tags: ios, logging, nslog

Now I searched a while, but didn't found any information about how [NSLog](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Functions/#//apple_ref/c/func/NSLog) works in regards to log file rotation.

Are there any file size limits? How many files will be saved? How far back can the log go? What does iOS do if the device gets low on memory? I think it will clean these files?

Comment: Good questions all (voted). Sadly I don't know the answer, but I'm hoping somebody chimes in who does.